# Save selected option drawer activity for use in back button

Tags: android, android-fragments, drawerlayout

I have a drawer activity and a method that calls several fragments, when I select an option shows me a listview with buttons. Clicking a button sends me to a new activity that has a back button. I want to return to the previous screen, return to the option you select in the drawer activity.

```
 public class DrawerOpcionesActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.drawer_menu);
          ....
          drawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
              mostrarFragment(position);
              adapterOpciones.setPositionCheked(position);
           }
         });

         if(savedInstanceState == null){
            mostrarFragment(0);
          }
        ...
 } 

 private void mostrarFragment(int position){
    Fragment fragment = null;

    System.out.println("opcion: " + position);

    switch (position) {
        case 1:
            fragment = new LineasTransporteFragment();
            break;

   ....
  }
```

In the other activity...

```
 @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.xxxxx);

      actionBar = getActionBar();
      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
  }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            ... //new Intent.. I dont Know who call the save option from activity drawerOptions
            return true;
    default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
 }
```

I need to save the selected option, when I call a new Intent show me the selected option. I show the fragment of default position 0

Comment: You may use SharedPrefrence of android to save the state and access back the state. Please have a look for sharedPrefrence

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use SharedPrefrence of android to save the state and access back the state. Please have a look for sharedPrefrence